# iPad Newsstand Subscriber Information (name, email, zip)

Tags: ipad, itunes, subscriber

When users purchase a magazine subscription on my iPad Newsstand app they get prompted to share some info:

**Share your Information? The publisher of [app name here] would like your name, email, and zip code for use in accordance with their privacy policy.**

However, I can't seem to find subscriber information within iTunes Connect. Can anyone help me find this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the Sales and Trends section.  You should have the option to download the Opt-In Report, which is a password-protected ZIP file.  The password is displayed by clicking the Opt-In Passkey button.

Source: http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf